# Add alternative service implementation to the classpath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, cdi, weld

I have some CDI application which is started as a fatjar with a bootstrap main class:

```
java $ARGS -jar foo_cdi.jar
```

For some reasons **I can not change this command line and I can not change `foo_cdi.jar`**.

But I can configure `$ARGS` environment variable.

What I need, is to add some additional `additional.jar` into the classpath (supposing, that it is located in the same directory as `foo.jar`).

This `additional.jar` contains alternative implementations of some services, used in my CDI application inside `foo_cdi.jar`.

Certainly `additional.jar` contains `META-INF/beans.xml` with scan/include pathes and compiled classes marked with

```
@Alternative
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION + 1)
```

However that just setting `ARGS` as `-classpath additional.jar` doesn't work. I guess this is because of `-jar` option:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

So my question: is any way to solve this puzzle?

Only one hack-solution I was advised at the moment, is to use own `javaagent` which will redefine needed classes with my own implementations. But it seems to me that this is an obscene and dirty hack.

(Though I can do:

`java -javaagent:additional.jar foo_cdi.jar`)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-Xbootclasspath/a:additional.jar` for Java 8 to append the library to the boot classpath.